# How to drag svgs inserted by button click?

Tags: svg, canvas, drag

What I'm trying to do is insert svg circles by clicking button to the workspace. Beside that, I want to free drag all those circles.
Can you help me the code?

```js
document.getElementById('draw').addEventListener('click', function(){

document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = 
'<svg height="100" width="100">' + 
  '<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="rgba(130,130,130,0.6)">' + 
'</svg>';

});
```

```html
<button id="draw">Draw Circle</button>
<div id="here"></div>
```

Comment: [This](https://codepen.io/ahsanrathore/pen/jMjdez) might help you.

Comment: Thanks. It's helpful, I need to do something like the example you linked, but instead drawing pixels, but svg content (vectors). If you have an example like that one for svg it'd be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I was amazed that creating an SVG like this would work, and it works! (on IE too). However it creates problems when trying to work with events. I prefer to create the SVG element and the circle element using `createElementNS` and use `appendChild` to append them to the DOM

```js
const SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
const SVG_XLINK = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";


/*let innerSVG = '<svg height="100" width="100">' + 
  '<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="rgba(130,130,130,0.6)">' + 
'</svg>';*/

let svgdata =  {width:100,height:100}
let circledata = {cx:50,cy:50,r:40}
// creating a new SVG element using the data
let svg = newSVG(svgdata);
// creating a new circle element using the data and appending it to the svg
let circle = drawCircle(circledata, svg);
// the offset between the click point on the SVG and the left upper corner of the SVG
let offset={}
// a flag to control the dragging
let dragging = false;
// the mouse position
let m;
document.getElementById('draw').addEventListener('click', function(){

here.appendChild(svg)});


// events
here.addEventListener("mousedown",(evt)=>{
  dragging = true;
  offset = oMousePos(svg, evt);
})

here.addEventListener("mousemove",(evt)=>{
  if(dragging){
   m = oMousePos(here, evt);
   svg.style.top = (m.y - offset.y)+"px";
   svg.style.left = (m.x - offset.x)+"px";
  }
})

here.addEventListener("mouseup",(evt)=>{
  dragging = false;
})




function drawCircle(o, parent) {
  var circle = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'circle');
  for (var name in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      circle.setAttributeNS(null, name, o[name]);
    }
  }
  parent.appendChild(circle);
  return circle;
}


function newSVG(o) {
  let svg = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'svg');
  for (var name in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      svg.setAttributeNS(null, name, o[name]);
    }
  }
  return svg;
}



function oMousePos(elmt, evt) {
      let ClientRect = elmt.getBoundingClientRect();
                return { 
                x: Math.round(evt.clientX - ClientRect.left),
                y: Math.round(evt.clientY - ClientRect.top)
      }
}
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid;position:absolute;}

circle{
  stroke:black;stroke-width:1;fill:rgba(130,130,130,0.6);
}

#here{width:100%; height:100vh; background-color:#efefef;margin:0; padding:0; position:relative}
```

```html
<button id="draw">Draw Circle</button>
<div id="here"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It's very helpful, in fact Im surprised. But is there any chance that every time the button is clicked appear a new circle? (and all those new circles draging too)

Comment: I'm not very sure I understand you. You'll have to explain it in a different question. Meanwhile, please consider to accept my answer.